# Android native Gradle not working because of .aar files conflict

Tags: android, gradle, aar

In my project I have .aar files. Now when I am adding new .aar file it gives me below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.zebra.adc.decoder.a found in modules jetified-MswipeWseriesUniversalDRDSDKVer1.0.23(Beta)v3.7.3-runtime (MswipeWseriesUniversalDRDSDKVer1.0.23(Beta)v3.7.3.aar) and jetified-mosambeelib_v_aar_1.0.0.122-runtime (mosambeelib_v_aar_1.0.0.122.aar)
```

My app gradle is

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar', 'MswipeWseriesUniversalDRDSDKVer1.0.23(Beta)v3.7.3.aar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation fileTree(include: ['mosambeelib_v_aar_1.0.0.122.aar'], dir: 'libs')
```

I have tried to exclude module but its not working.

Comment: Seems like the aar files are "FAT" (including dependencies). Better check if they are available as regular dependency in a Maven repository and use it from there, then dependencies will be automatically merged and only applied once.